# Running node commands as part of a grunt driven QUnit test

Tags: node.js, qunit, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to package my jQuery plugin. As part of the QUnit tests, I need to run a node command before the tests start to get a consistent result (something like `process.env.TZ = 'Europe/London'` as my plugin deals with timezones, so results will be different in different timezones).

So my question is: How can you run a node specific command as part of the qunit tests?

Thanks.

Comment: See if the [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) API helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit more research, I came across grunt-env @ https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-env

That allows different environment tasks to be defined in the gruntfile, e.g.

```
env: {
    setTZ : {
        TZ : 'Europe/London'
    }
}
```

which will define the task `env:setTZ` to set the timezone. And yes, whilst setting the timezone can be problematic, advice appears to be that so long as you only do it the once, you're OK: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/rt8EFR6gdi8/i2Fdp2vDPFQJ

> you can set TZ just once, further changes won't get picked up.

Luckily, that's plenty sufficient for my use case, and it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own grunt task and call the qunit task from inside it:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

grunt.registerTask('qunit-plus', 'Custom qunit task', function() {
    exec('/usr/bin/mycmd', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        grunt.task.run('qunit');
    });
});
```

Then call it with:

```
$ grunt qunit-plus
```

NOTE: untested.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the original question; `process.env.TZ = 'Europe/London'` is a *node* command (to set the timezone), not a command-line command.

Comment: It sounds like that node command is unreliable: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3286. If using something like node-time inside the custom grunt task doesn't work, then you could patch grunt's qunit task (node_modules/grunt/tasks/qunit.js).